# Onclick functions not firing in handlebarJS, requireJS, BackboneJS and underscoreJS combination

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I am using requireJS with backboneJS and underscoreJS in my application.
I am using handlebarJS to load the contents dynamically. in the handlebars, i am adding onclick functions from parsed JSON data.

A Sample Handlebar :

```
{{#each this}}
<a href="#" onclick="{{Function}}">{{Link}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

I am getting a perfect result for these handlebars,

Result :

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc(1)">Function 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc(2,3)">Function 2</a>
```

But the function `myfun(param)` is not fired since, i haven't invoked the file in requireJS.

becoz, I have various function to be populated that are in various files.
I can not include all those files all the time. I want only the necessary files to be loaded when the handle bars are loaded with those onclick functions.

Eg :
 **i have myfun(param) in a module fun.js
 and myfunc(param1,param2) in another module func.js**

**I am populating the Handlebar using a view in myview.js**

**I need only the module to be loaded only when i click that function which is in it.**

Could anyone suggest me with a sample working onclick requireJS.

Comment: you shouldn't use event handlers like that. use backbone events.

Comment: Thanks, but, is there any other way?

Comment: it is the preferred way if you are going to do anything with backbone.

Comment: Don't you hate those replies that say "Don't do it like that" but they never say how to actually do it? @Prabakaran what are you iterating with {{each this}}? a collection?

Comment: @ErickRuizdeChavez Here, i am not using any collection. I am getting it as a json from web services. And i process those json and i am loading in the handlebars.

Comment: What if you put that Handlebars template in a module that depends on the module `fun.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to trigger events from HTML with this combination.
You are forced to use backbone Events only / Jquery events